# SQL should find a group that includes exactly 2 specified values and check the total number of elements in the group (supplement my query)

Tags: mysql, sql

Initially we have such a table

| contact_id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

After that I make a query to search for groups containing the values of contacts 1 and 3

```
SELECT `group_id` ,COUNT(DISTINCT(`contact_id`)) AS `variants` 
FROM `TaskTeam_member` 
WHERE `contact_id`='1' OR `contact_id`='3' 
GROUP BY `group_id` 
HAVING `variants`='2'
```

it turns out that such a table (correct)

| contact_id | variants |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

And now I need to add in addition to searching for values 1 and 3 in the group to check the total number of elements in it (I need 2), that is, if presumably there are elements 1 and 3 in group 1, but the total number of elements is 3 and not 2 as in the example above, then this group should not be output

the result should be like this

| contact_id | variants |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |

help me complete my request!

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id)`

Comment: SELECT `group_id` ,COUNT(*) AS `variants` FROM `TaskTeam_member` WHERE `contact_id`='1' OR `contact_id`='3' GROUP BY `group_id` HAVING `variants`='2' .This query no help.it still gives out 2 groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for other contact_ids you need to include all records, but only count the ones you want:

```
SELECT `group_id`
FROM `TaskTeam_member` 
GROUP BY `group_id` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id)=2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE contact_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 3 THEN 3 END)=2
```